# How to create a C++ project in VS Code and link main, functions and header?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, project

I am unable to create a multifile project in Visual Studio Code.

I've tried multiple extensions, manual folder creations, linking with paths to header files. The result is that is is impossible to compile anything.

I would like it to do in a similar way as in the tutorial for VS: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/programs-with-multiple-code-files/

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functions.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    cout << "return value is: " << add(3,4);
    cout << "\nreturn value is: " << add(1.2,3.4);
    cout << "\nreturn value is: " << add(5);

    return 0;
}
```

functions.cpp:

```
double add ( double x, double y)
{
    return x + y;
}

int add ( int x)
{
    return add(1.2,3.4) + x;
}
```

functions.h:

```
double add ( double x, double y);
int add ( int x);
```

I want the whole thing to compile, nothing else. Now I am getting an error as those files are not linked as a project. How can I do it in a similar way as in the link provided?

Comment: Do you have #include "functions.h" in the functions.cpp file?

Comment: I expect `functions.cpp` is not part of your project.

Comment: no, I do not - added it and still does not link.

Comment: The issue here isn't the code. The issue is the steps you've taken to create the project. Since you haven't make any real attempt to describe them it's very hard to help. Maybe you should just search for a tutorial on the internet?

Comment: There aren't really "projects" in VS Code, it's not an IDE like Visual Studio, it doesn't even include a compiler. You can always use the integrated terminal, though, and type the needed commands, like `g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp functions.cpp`.

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Code does not have a build system for C++ code included. It is not like Visual Studio. You might want to use a build system like CMake which integrates nicely in VS Code

Comment: OK, so there is no way to run this as a project in VSC I get it. I need to find some project extension such as C/C+ Project Generator ( found it now) or just move on to Visual Studio...

Answer (score 2):

Because VScode is not an IDE, you cannot do the same things in VScode as in VS. Therefore, the only possible way is:

```cpp
#include "filename.cpp"
```

But in the tutorial, this is described as wrong, therefore I recommend you to switch your programming platform. It sucks, I also had to do it.

Comment: Whilst this works, it's not recommended practise to include cpp files like this. For anyone who doesn't want to switch platform, I suggest reading up on the 'tasks.json' file and how you can tweak the default settings for building a multifile project