# Can't link header files to my main.cpp in VScode (macOS) (clang error)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, linker

I am trying to link a header file which has a class defined in it and a .cpp file that has the actual functions of that class to my main cpp file but I'm getting this error:

c++     DataMembers.cpp   -o DataMembers
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"Cat::eat()", referenced from:
_main in DataMembers-053507.o
"Cat::meow()", referenced from:
_main in DataMembers-053507.o
"Cat::sleep()", referenced from:
_main in DataMembers-053507.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [DataMembers] Error 1

Please note that all files exists in the same directory!

my main.cpp code is:

```cpp
#include "Cat.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Cat myCat;

    myCat.eat();
    myCat.meow();
    myCat.sleep();
}
```

my Cat.h code:

```cpp
#ifndef CAT_H_
#define CAT_H_

class Cat 
{
public:
    void meow();
    void sleep();
    void eat();
};

#endif
```

and Cat.cpp code is:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Cat.h"
using namespace std;

void Cat::meow()
{
    cout << "Meowwwwww!" << endl;
    return;
}

void Cat::sleep()
{
    cout << "Zzz ... " << endl;
    return;
}

void Cat::eat()
{
    cout << "Num Nom Nom .. Yummy" << endl;
    return;
}
```

Interesting thing is when I change the header file in my main.cpp from `#inclue "Cat.h"`
into `#include "Cat.cpp"` the program compiles without any issues! I just don't know why?

I have searched for a solution but couldn't find any yet! and I need to be able to use header files I create myself!

Thank you in advance friends!

Comment: Your vscode build command is only building `main.cpp`

Comment: And how to fix that? How to link all files together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When compiling make sure that you reference all the `cpp` source files so it can generate the according object files.

It seems like you forgot to reference `cat.cpp`. The compiler sees that you have a header file included, assuming the implementation of this class will be in another `cpp` file. Because you forgot to reference the said file, the linker will complain that some undefined symbols cannot be linked.

Once you included the `cat.cpp` directly into your `main.cpp`, you basically copied all its contents to this file, which means there is no need anymore to link the implementation from another translation unit.

In short: you need to tell your compiler about `cat.cpp`

Comment: How to reference the ```Cat.cpp```  file? Do you mean to include it in the headers as a ```.cpp``` file?
Sorry but I am new to VSCODE

Comment: I personally don't use vscode so i don't know exactly how you need to specify it there. You should have a file in which you can specify your compile options, in there you have to add the `cat.cpp` file. If you want to compile it in your terminal you could do it like this: `g++ -o main ./main.cpp ./cat.cpp && ./main`

Comment: I just tried it and it works when compiling it using terminal but I want this to be automatically compiled and linked not me having to include the ```.cpp``` files of all headers in the terminal! is there anyway? also what is the term of this issue  that i should search google for ?? Thanks a lot

Comment: You don't need to specify the `cpp` files seperately, if you want to compile every `cpp` file from your current dir you can just use: `g++ -o main ./*.cpp && ./main`. Like i said there will be a way in vscode to specify which source files you want to compile. If you want to know more about this, i would suggest you taking a further look at how a c++/c application is compiled, this includes e.g.: `preprocessing`, `compiling`, `linking`, as this is a very important concept to understand when working with c++/c.

Answer (score 0):

First Check For Which Architecture You Have Written the Header File For, If it is the Same Architecture as the Main File, Then Try Using Full Path From the Drive, Even then It is Not Working, Add Your Header File Path as an Additional Include Directories.

Comment: Sorry for being so noob here but can you please explain how can I do that actually?

Answer (score 0):

try this in main.cpp

```
#include "Cat.cpp"
```

instead of:

```
#include "Cat.h"
```

source:
[How to create a C++ project in VS Code and link main, functions and header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478965/how-to-create-a-c-project-in-vs-code-and-link-main-functions-and-header)

Answer (score -2):

In Cat.cpp you wrote #include "cat.h" but the file name is "Cat.h" so you messed up the capitalization.

Comment: Sorry, I just fixed that! I typed it incorrectly. Anyways Fixing the capitalization didn't fix the issue!